# Extract string and relative float from column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a column with extracted information from another column in Pandas.

First, this only applies to rows where `ID` contains string 'CODE'. Then extract string 'CODE' and the float following it until a space appears or at the end of the float.

```
ID                        value1     value2    value3   Date
ICO54 XT   317            10         10        1000     2010-04-07
IP006 CODE 504            20         11        3000     2000-12-07
CODE99 2B06 NHH           20         130       8000     2001-10-18
CODE 133L                 20         10        18000    2001-10-21
CODE 196 ES MHE CXX NH053 8          100       12000    2009-08-12
CODE131ESAGEMSHRGEM014    8          100       12000    2009-08-12
```

Expected output:

```
ID                        value1     value2    value3   Date        new_col
ICO54 XT   317            10         10        1000     2010-04-07  NaN
IP006 CODE 504            20         11        3000     2000-12-07  CODE 504
CODE99 2B06 NHH           20         130       8000     2001-10-18  CODE 99 
CODE 133L                 20         10        18000    2001-10-21  CODE 133
CODE 196 ES MHE CXX NH053 8          100       12000    2009-08-12  CODE 196 
CODE131ESAGEMSHRGEM014    8          100       12000    2009-08-12  CODE 131
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. @TimBiegeleisen's answer does not output a fixed space between CODE and the number
2. @Corralien's answer requires two regex steps
3. @balalala does not output the required format

Here is an alternative to complete the previous answers' limitations ;)

```
df['new_col'] = 'CODE '+df['ID'].str.findall(r'CODE\s*(\d+)').str[0]
```

other possibility:

```
df['new_col'] = 'CODE '+df['ID'].str.extract(r'CODE\s*(\d+)')[0]
```

output:

```
                          ID  value1  value2  value3        Date   new_col
0               ICO54 XT 317      10      10    1000  2010-04-07       NaN
1             IP006 CODE 504      20      11    3000  2000-12-07  CODE 504
2            CODE99 2B06 NHH      20     130    8000  2001-10-18   CODE 99
3                  CODE 133L      20      10   18000  2001-10-21  CODE 133
4  CODE 196 ES MHE CXX NH053       8     100   12000  2009-08-12  CODE 196
5     CODE131ESAGEMSHRGEM014       8     100   12000  2009-08-12  CODE 131
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `str.extract`:

```py
df["new_col"] = df["ID"].str.extract(r'CODE\s*(\d+)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract` as suggested by @TimBiegeleisen:

```
>>> df['new_col'] = df["ID"].str.extract(r'CODE\s*(\d+)', expand=False) \
                            .str.replace(r'(\d+)', r'CODE \1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                          ID  value1  value2  value3        Date   new_col
0              ICO54 XT  317      10      10    1000  2010-04-07       NaN
1             IP006 CODE 504      20      11    3000  2000-12-07  CODE 504
2            CODE99 2B06 NHH      20     130    8000  2001-10-18   CODE 99
3                  CODE 133L      20      10   18000  2001-10-21  CODE 133
4  CODE 196 ES MHE CXX NH053       8     100   12000  2009-08-12  CODE 196
5     CODE131ESAGEMSHRGEM014       8     100   12000  2009-08-12  CODE 131
```

Answer (score 1):

use `extract`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['IP006 CODE 504','CODE99','CODE 133L','CODE 196 ES MHE']})
df.ID.str.extract(r'.*?(CODE).*?(\d{1,}).*?')
```

It gets:

```
Out[21]: 
      0    1
0  CODE  504
1  CODE   99
2  CODE  133
3  CODE  196
```